# Pandoc --toc Command is not working right

Tags: pandoc

Following the document, I am using `--toc` and `-s/--standalone` command to generate table of content(toc). After converting from .html to .docx, opening file in Word, the result would be like this, the table of content is gone.

[image]

Then open same file in MacOS Pages, toc is displayed but the format looks damn weird.

[image]

Any thought on this? thanks in advance.